# I'm using AWS DataSync from on-premise to Amazon S3, If I delete the data in on-premise, will it sync to Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio, aws-datasync

Does AWS DataSync sync the file that has been deleted in on-premise to Amazon S3, so from both location it is gone/deleted? If yes, can I turn off this feature? How?

I've read the documentation for both AWS DataSync and Amazon S3, and I didn't find a solution about this explicitly (maybe I missed it)

Answer (score 0):

From [How AWS DataSync transfers work - AWS DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/how-datasync-transfer-works.html):

> A *task* describes a DataSync transfer. It identifies a source and destination location along with details about how to copy data between those locations. You also can specify how a task treats metadata, **deleted files**, and permissions.

Also, from [Managing how AWS DataSync transfers files, objects, and metadata - AWS DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/configure-metadata.html):

> Select **Keep deleted files** if you want DataSync to maintain files or objects in the destination location that don't exist in the source.
>
> If you don't choose this option and your task deletes objects from your Amazon S3 bucket, you might incur minimum storage duration charges for certain storage classes.
>
> **Warning:** You can't deselect this option and enable **Transfer all data**. When you transfer all data, DataSync doesn't scan your destination location and doesn't know what to delete.